# How to get field data from opened webpage using c#

Tags: c#, php

I have php website on server and c# winform on client.

is there any way to get field value of the php current page using c#?

for example, in the php I have firstName field of customer (he just typed it) and I need to use this value in the c# program.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: encode your php informations as JSON and get it in your C# form. this is why JSON is created

Comment: Sounds good, can you please advise me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

suppose u have a php script in which you get firstName (let's say getName.php):

```
<?php
$firstName = $_POST['firstName']; // or any other way to get it
$arr = array('firstname' => $firstName);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

this will show something like this:

```
{"firstname": your_firstname }
```

so now this JSON can be used in any programming language that you want. In your case for C#:

Use the WebClient class in System.Net:

```
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("url_of_php_file");
```

Keep in mind that WebClient is IDisposable, so you would probably add a using statement to this in production code. This would look like:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   var json = wc.DownloadString("url_of_php_file");
}
```

Comment: @ofirparnass it helped??

Comment: unfortunately no because i can't access the page with the field without visiting the index.php before. any suggestions?